# Movie theatre permutation word problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, solution-verification, word-problem

This is the question I am attempting.

> If there are 4 girls and 4 boys going to a movie theatre, in how many
> different arrangements could they sit together if…
>
> a) the first and last seats were occupied by girls
>
> and
>
> b) all the girls want to sit together?

And this is what I have done:

---

a) There are 4 girls, and the first and last spaces are taken by girls in 4P2 (nPr) ways. After the 2 girls have taken a seat, there are now 6! ways in which the rest of the group can sit (4 boys and 2 girls remaining).

Meaning the total number of ways for them to be seated in 4P2 * 6! (I'm not sure if this is correct)

---

b) All the girls want to sit together this time. If we take all 4 of the girls as one entity then we will have 4 + 1 = 5 total entities to shuffle around. Therefore this seating arrangement has 5! ways and the 4 girls can be arranged in 4! ways.

Meaning the total number of ways for them to be seated in 5! * 4!

---

I would like to know if my analysis and thought process is correct.

Comment: Pl show what work you have done, and where you are stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by 'all the girls want to sit together'?  ... because if that means that all 4 of them have to be in one block, that's obviously not going to work out given condition a)

Comment: I have edited my question, hopefully it shows all the work I have put into this quesiton

Comment: are questions (a) and (b) separate?

Comment: @Jamāl yes they are

Comment: well in that case, your thought process and solutions are correct.

Comment: well awesome! thank you so much for the feedback! appreciate it :)

Comment: parts a) and b) can simply be written like this right: a) 8640 ways (this seems wrong...) and b) 2880 ways?

Comment: Why does part a) seem wrong to you?

Comment: Its just that the number seems far too great. But like you said, my math is correct, so I have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117734/discussion-between-jaml-and-esker-luminous).